# How to Use API in Component TS Code

Tags: angular, angular-material

In Angular Materials documentation, there is an API with useful functions to do with that component, such as https://material.angular.io/components/list/api

Is there any way to get that object in the component typescript code? For example, say in my component I want to listen to the selectChange events. 
I tried the following code, but it said that myOptionId does not exist on type myComponent

**.html**

```
  <mat-selection-list>
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of list"  #myOptionID>
      {{item.id}}
    </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
```

**.ts**

```
  constructor() {
    this.selectionEvents = this.myOptionID.selectChange;
  }

  selectionEvents: EventEmitter<MatSelectionListOptionEvent>;
```

Is there any way to get a reference to a material object inside the component so that I can do things with it in typescript code?

P.S: I am aware of code that goes into the template like

```
(selectChange)="onChange($event)"
```

But I would also like to change the selected options based on logic in the backend, so I would like to access the whole object in the component code

Comment: You cannot even use `(selectChange)="onChange($event)"` now because it is a bug. In the master branch you would see that they are changing this to `selectionChange`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your component do,

```
// grab the MatListOption instances..
@ViewChildren(MatListOption) options: QueryList<MatListOption>;
```

and in your ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit whatever..

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.getData(data => {
        // say you want to check the third one.
        this.options.toArray[2].selected = true;
    })
}
```

A [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-mbc9ln?file=app/app.component.ts) for you where I can grab the instances of the options and after three seconds from code i check the third menu list. I hope that solves your issue.

And note that

```
<mat-list-option (selectChange)="onChange($event)" value="bananas">Bananas</mat-list-option>
```

is still not functional because on current `2.0.0-beta.12` you would se they have never called `.emit` on `selectChange` it's just sitting there doing nothing. [code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/2.0.0-beta.12/src/lib/list/selection-list.ts#L124)

But as seen on master branch, they have changed `selectChange` to `selectionChange` where they have actually called `.emit` so it should work on master. [code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/list/selection-list.ts#L121)